# Parse data from MondoDB Atlas

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parsing, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to get some values from DB in cluster (MongoDB). Using Stitch.

Now I have this to get data.

```
const client = stitch.Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient('application-...');
const db_data = client.getServiceClient(stitch.RemoteMongoClient.factory, 'mongodb-atlas').db('Name').collection("Name");
data = db_data.find({}, {}).asArray();
console.log(data);
```

It looks like.

[image]

But I can`t realize how to parse it to JSON or just put some values to variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` function returns a promise, which is what you see in your posted image. You need to handle that promise with `.then()` like the following:

```
const client = stitch.Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient('application-...');
const db_data = client.getServiceClient(stitch.RemoteMongoClient.factory, 'mongodb-atlas').db('Name').collection("Name");
data = db_data.find({}, {}).asArray().then((data) => console.log(data));
```

[Here's a relevant example for you!](https://www.javatpoint.com/mongodb-stitch)